# How to set a PowerShell script variable from a module?

Tags: powershell, variables, module, scope

Is it possible to set a value of a variable with the `script` scope from a module (`.psm1` file)? The following does not work because, from what I've read, `script` scope in a module is not really a `script` scope.

*TestScope.psm1*

```
function Initialize-TestVariable {
param (
    [string]
    $Name
)
    $scope      = "Script"
    $visibility = "Public"

    Set-Variable -Scope $scope -Name $Name -Value "Set in module" -Force -Visibility $visibility
}

Export-ModuleMember -Function *
```

*TestScope.ps1*

```
param (
    [string]
    $Value = "Default value"
)

$path = Join-Path (Split-Path -Path $PSCommandPath -Parent) 'TestScope.psm1'
Import-Module $path -ErrorAction Stop

Initialize-TestVariable -Name "Value"

$Value
```

*Output*

```
Default value
```

I need output to be:

```
Set in module
```

If anyone wonders why I need this, there is a valid reason (so I'm not interested in the discussion whether this is a good idea, just need to know if this can be done, and, if so, how). Also, using the `global` scope is not an option, since it changes the state (there will be hanging global variables after the script exits that were not there when the script started).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I figured it out:

*TestScope.psm1*

```
function Initialize-TestVariable {
    [CmdletBinding()]
    param (
        [string]
        $Name
    )

    $PSCmdlet.SessionState.PSVariable.Set($Name, "Set in module")
}

Export-ModuleMember -Function *
```